# Magento 2.1 CE installed but front/back-end not loading

Tags: php, magento

I am new to Magento and trying to install it myself but can't see it working after installing it successfully.

I followed [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html) instructions and installed PHP56, MySQL 5.7 & phpMyAdmin and then followed the following steps to install Magento 2.1 CE:

1. sudo su
2. vi /etc/php.ini
3. ?always_populate_raw_post_data
4. I
5. always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
6. :wq
7. service httpd restart
8. sudo yum install php56-intl –y
9. service httpd restart
10. mkdir /var/www/html/magento2ce
11. upload magento tar file to /var/www/html/magento2ce and unzip using tar command
12. cd /var/www/html/magento2ce
13. tar zxf Magento-CE-2.1.1-2016-08-29-06-31-39.tar.gz

And before installation I used following command to assign [permissions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html) to magento folders:

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2ce && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} \; && find var vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} \; && chown -R :apache . && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

And after all that I stared Setup Wizard which ran successfully.
But nothing works when I try to access front/backend.
Can any one please let me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After installing Magento 2, you need to run some commands through command line (cmd) in your root directory.

A) Upgrade command : php bin/magento setup:upgrade

B) Deploy command : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
If your store has multi-language then you need to mention all the language         code during running deploy command.
For example : php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US, nl_NL, fr_FR

C) Reinxing command : php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: Thanks Abhinav, I tried your solution but its throwing error on Step 2: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /var/www/html/magento2ce/vendor/oyejorge/less.php/li                                                                                                                               b/Less/Parser.php on line 740